# In iTerm2, I can't run `ls` with both -a and -w flags. When I just run `ls`, I get columns, but when I run `ls -a`, it's all just in a single column

Tags: iterm, zsh

I'm transferring from Terminal to iTerm2 and am trying to set up my shortcuts. The problem is that when I run `ls -a`, everything is in one column whereas if I just run `ls`, it shows up in several columns. I even tried adding the `-w` flag, but that won't work.

I'd like to be able to execute `ls -a` and have the files show up in several columns.

Comment: Something that appears as a dot file causes the column width to be too wide.

Comment: Did it work as expected in Terminal?

Comment: @pekasus : This is not related to the terminal program `ls` is running in. `ls` has no idea what "terminal" app is hosting the `zsh` which in turn is spawning the `ls` process. I could imagine that the tty settings have an effect; you may compare the output from `stty` in both terminals. Also - just for the safe side - check the value of the variables `COLUMNS`, `TERM`, `ZSH_VERSION`, `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE`, although I doubt that they do have an influence. Also ensure that you are running the identical `ls` (verify by doing a `type ls` in both environments).

Comment: What happens if you do a `ls -aC`?

Comment: @user1934428 it still shows up as a single column.

Comment: @nohillside in terminal when I run ls -a I still get columns

Comment: @pekasus : And what is with the other checks I suggested?

Comment: Ah, and one check more, which *could* reveal something: In both apps, do a `echo $-` and see whether you get the same output.

Comment: Have both iTerm and Terminal the same size (width)?